# How to call the Image function With in UIImagePickerViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

How to call this function with in UIImagePickerviewcontroller

```
- (UIImage*)imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = self;

    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;

    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;

    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;

    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;

    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;

    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO)
    {
        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;

        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;


        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
        }
        else
        {
            scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
        }

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;

        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else
        {
            if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            {
                thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
            }
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); // this will crop

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;

    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;

    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;

    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");
    }

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}



- (UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
  {
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);

        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

         return cropped;

    }
```

Comment: what is your problem. can you explain it

Comment: Can you explain in more detail in the question what you are attempting to do and what is not working?

Comment: when i call this function in UIImagepickerviewcontroller it gives the  error like :[profileViewController size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9bbd460'

Comment: Can you share the code you have been using to call this function please?

Comment: UIImage *img2=[self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:image tarCGSizeMake(160.0f,240.0f)];This is my code

Comment: Can u please suggest me Adam if any wrong in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

   UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   img = [self imageByCropping:img toRect:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 80)]; // pass size as you need.

   /// Here you got cropped image 

   img = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(170, 180);] // pass size as you need;

   UIImageView *imgSetAlarmTime = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
   imgSetAlarmTime.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 100); 
   [imgSetAlarmTime setImage: img];
   [self.view addSubview: imgSetAlarmTime];
}
```